# onCreate not called when restarting activity after it is destroyed

Tags: android

When I exit my app (by pressing back or the home button) the `Activity`s `onDestroy()` method is called (where I do lots of clean up with bitmaps).

When I reopen the app, `onCreate()` does not get called... it goes straight to `onStart()`, despite the fact that the `Activity` was finished. This is causing a "trying to use a recycled bitmap" error.

Is there a way to ensure that `onCreate()` is always called after an `Activity` is destroyed?

EDIT: I was mistaken. onCreate() IS being called. However, I am still getting the "trying to use a recycled bitmap" error. If onCreate() is going through all of it's steps, wouldn't any recycled bitmaps be reloaded?

Comment: Android version? Device? How do you verify that it isn't called?

Comment: when you press the home button , the activity is not destroyed , it is  just in background , and the method onPause() is called,  and when you launch it again , the method onResume() will be executed, the method onDestroy() is executed when you press the back button , and then when you try to re launch your activity , the onCreate() will be executed

Comment: When you pressHome button the activity usually goes to `onStop()` not `onDestroy()`. Write some log messages `onCreate()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` to ensure that you are not missing anything ...

Comment: Yes, I have log messages that verify what is being called. onDestroy definitely gets called (and it recycles the bitmaps, which is why I get the recycled bitmap error). When I relaunch, it skips onCreate, and goes to onStart and then onResume.

Comment: Posting at least your onDestroy may help. Something doesn't add up because of the way apps handle closing, as others have already stated

Comment: Where and how do you define the bitmap instances?  If they are exclusively declared in your Activity, then you are doing something else wrong. Please post your code.  If you are declaring them outside the activity, then you are definitely doing something wrong.  Please post your code (just the relevant bits please)  PS.  If the activity lifecycle was broken on your device/Android combination, then I doubt that ANY app would run, including the launcher.  PPS.  onCreate goes through your steps, not "it's steps".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I was setting the ImageView image. My original way to load an image from /res was:

```
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage)); //WRONG!!!!
```

apparently if you recycled a bitmap, the above code will not reallocate memory for the bitmap, and your program will crash when it tries to draw that ImageView.

The correct way to load a bitmap that has been recycled (or at least, the way that solved my problem) is:

```
    image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myImage))); //correct!
```

It still doesn't answer my question as to why, after exiting the app, and onDestroy is called, that when I re-enter the app, it is looking for a recycled bitmap. In theory the app should be starting up from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Your app must be doing something to forcefully ensure that onDestroy gets called, because if you look at the Activity lifecycle there's no path to get back to onStart from onDestroy that doesn't include onCreate.  In reality, an Activity unwinds its initialization with reverse callbacks to the ones that bring it into the resumed state.  Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) Perhaps you're calling the finish() method somewhere to force quite the Activity?

Comment: You are correct. The onCreate log was overlooked. So, onCreate IS being called, but I am still getting the trying to use a recycled bitmap error.

Comment: The recycled bitmap error has to do with how you're calling createBitmap and not to do with the Activity lifecycle.  You'd need to supply a code snippet of what's going on in application to know why you're getting that error.  I'm assuming that you're calling Bitmap::recycle on a bitmap that you intend to render to the screen and the recycle command is executing before your render command, but without supplying any code, that's all I got

Comment: Or perhaps holding a static reference (or some other leak) to a bitmap outside the activity which loads it?

Comment: I am using drawables. I recycle them by checking if the drawable is an instance of BitmapDrawable and then I cast the Drawable to BitmapDrawable get the bitmap, and the recycle it.

Comment: It sounds like you are recycling it and then still trying to use it afterward

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If it did, can you accept my answer so that others who search for it will know the solution might also apply to them?

Answer (score 0):

when you press the home button , the activity is not destroyed , it is just sent to background , and the method `onPause()` is called, and when you launch it again , the method `onResume()` will be executed, the method `onDestroy()` is executed when you press the back button or when you call the method `finish()` to force the activity to be destroyed , and then when you try to re launch your activity , the `onCreate()` will be executed.

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)